# Golang GRPC почему не правильно билдится .proto файл?

Tags: golang, grpc

Изучаю GRPC и не могу взять в толк что я делаю не так.
Есть проект GRPC есть на него примеры.
Среди прочих есть вот такой простейший .proto файл и его билд.
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/helloworld/helloworld
В частности в билде есть вот такой код

```
func RegisterGreeterServer(s *grpc.Server, srv GreeterServer) {
s.RegisterService(&_Greeter_serviceDesc, srv)
```

Но если я скачиваю файл .proto и делаю его билд у себя на машине у меня этого кода нет.
Этот файл не допускается редактировать в ручную. Нет понимания как так получается, может кто подскажет?
Билд делаю командой protoc -I=D:\testproto --go_out=D:\testproto\ D:\testproto\2.proto

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо не самому вызывать `protoc`, а использовать `go generate`.

В greeter_server/main.go есть соответствующая директива

```
//go:generate protoc -I ../helloworld --go_out=plugins=grpc:../helloworld ../helloworld/helloworld.proto
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Вы направили меня по правильному пути. Оказывается не обязательно делать через go:generate, но необходимо изменить строку protoc как: --go_out=plugins=grpc: в этом месте была проблема. Ещё раз благодарю. Пошел дальше эксперементировать)